# Changing the name of the public folder in FuelPHP

Tags: .htaccess, fuelphp, mediatemple

I'm a complete newbie to fuel PHP. I've developed my application locally using MAMP as the environment with FuelPHP. Now other people are starting to become involved in the project so i'm trying to upload it somewhere for the rest of the team to review.

I created the site in a subfolder of my root directory directory (`htdocs`) on MAMP, so the path to the public folder is currently `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mediatemple-test/public/`.

I'm trying to initially get it working on our Media Temple Grid server, however I noticed that the root folder on Media Temple is called `html`. From reading other posts on here I understood that I should be able to just rename the `public` folder to `html`, however when I do this locally i get the following error:

> **Warning:** `require(/bootstrap.php)`: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mediatemple-test/public/index.php` on line 44
>   **Fatal error:** `require()`: Failed opening required `/bootstrap.php` (`include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php'`) in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mediatemple-test/public/index.php` on line 44

Do I need to change anything else or do I need to add a `.htaccess` file? If so, what do I need to put in there?

Also, does anybody have any advice for deploying FuelPHP to Media Temple Grid servers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the index.php and make sure all the filepaths are relative to your hosting.

APPPATH, DOCROOT, PKGPATH and COREPATH should all point to the correct locations.

If you have renamed the public folder to HTML where is the app folder? You should move that into mediatemple-test.

But... You shouldn't really be renaming folders, I would have just used htaccess to direct all traffic through public/index.php